# cant able to fetch what i stored in database with php pdo code

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

hey I am new to php and i try to upload image in database and display from database.

**Issue:**

When i try to fetch i am not be able to fetch the particular image always i got this  "array(0) { }" .so please help me clear this code .thanks in advance.

```
<?php
include'config.php';

if (isset($_POST["ok"])) {
$folder = "img/";
$image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$path = $folder.$image;
$target_file=$folder.basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$allowed = array('jpeg','png','jpg'); 
$filename = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if (!in_array($ext, $allowed)) {
    echo "sorry only jpg,jpeg,png and gif files are allowed";
}
else{
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $path);
    $sth=$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO sktable(image)VALUES('$image');SELECT 
image FROM sktable WHERE $image");
    $sth->execute();
    echo "<table border='2'>".
"<tr>".

    "<th>"."Image"."</th>".
"</tr>";


$select = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM sktable");

$select->execute();
$data=$select->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($data);
}
}
?>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="image"/>
<input type="submit" name="ok"/>
</form>

<style type="text/css">
#pimg{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Since you used `fetchAll()`, if you want to display all the data fetched, you need to use `foreach` and not `var_dump`

Answer (score 0):

Use `while` loop and print variable inside the loop.

```
 <?php
    $select = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM sktable");
    $select->execute();
    while ($row = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
       print_r($row);
    } 
    ?>
```

else  you can also use `foreach` loop

```
<?php
 $select = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM sktable");
 $select->execute();

foreach ($select->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {

}

?>
```

Comment: $select = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM sktable");

    $select->execute();
    $row = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    var_dump($row);
    while ($row = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
       print_r($row);

 ?>
 <tr>
  
  <td><img src="img/<?php echo $data['image'];?>" width="100" 
    height="100"></td>
  <?php
 }?>
 </tr>                                   for this code got bool false

Comment: try this <img src="img/<?php echo $row['image'];?>" width="100" height="100">

Comment: getting the same message "array(0){}"

Comment: can you print what are you getting in the `print_r($row)` ?

Comment: no its not printing ain't show any msg